# Site migration from .co.uk to previously owned .com to help with USA/global market reach?

Tags: seo, domains, internationalization, site-move

We own our domain .co.uk and have recently purchased the .com version from a third-party private seller.

My research shows that our .co.uk has a better domain authority score and low spam score when compared to the new .com.

Our business owner would like to move our website from .co.uk to .com so that .com is the main website as they feel a .com is more "global" and will increase exposure and conversion with USA-based (and other international) customers.

My gut feeling is that I am hesitant we migrate from .co.uk to .com and we should simply re-direct .com to .co.uk for international SEO we should:

.co.uk/us (for USA)
.co.uk/fr (for France)
.co.uk/de (for Germany)
.co.uk/jp (for Japan)
etc

There are risks associated with migration. Is it worth it?

(I hope my first question meets the requirements)